# how do I fix this error in my mass dm selfbot on discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, self

I am new to python, and I was trying to make a python selfbot that messages all my friends, but it keeps throwing up errors even when I try to fix it.

My code is

```
import discord
import os
import requests

token = input("Enter token: ")
head = {'Authorization': str(token)}
src = requests.get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me', headers=head)

if src.status_code == 401:
print("Invalid token.")
exit()
elif src.status_code == 200:
    print("Token accepted.")
else:
    print("Internal error.")
    input()
    exit()

T = input("Enter message: ")
if T == "text":
    exit(0)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    for user in client.user.friends:
        try:
            await user.send(T)
            print("Sent message:", user.name)
        except:
            print("Failed to send message:", user.name)

client.run(token)
```

Comment: and what is the error? what is your issue exactly?

Comment: why are you using requests and discord.py if you could just use discord.py instead? and discord selfbots are against discord tos.

Answer (score 0):

Selfbots are against discords terms of service and even if it wasnt you would get rate limited for spamming the api.